# netbeans java debugger uses source jar rather than project sources

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 11 to build/test a Java maven project. The main project POM has 6 modules. I have all modules open as projects in the IDE.  Project A has project B as a dependency. I want to run a test where I set a breakpoint in B and run a `Debug Test File` in module A.

The problem is that project A is loading B's sources from the jar file, not from my open project. So the breakpoints in project B are never actually registered.
Is there a way to configure my build/test so that debugging project A can locate breakpoints in project B?

Comment: Directly import the project in Netbeans without configuring other modules or sub module.

Comment: I've found there is a way to manually manipulate the sources for a project via Window -> Debugging -> Sources.  Then right-click to add a source folder. Then move entries up or down in list to adjust priority.  This seems to address my problem, despite being awkward. Is it the only way?